# Android: Navigation with Hilt + Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, framework, webcomponent, kotlin-compose

The project is simple:
Login screen and a forgot password screen. You can navigate from Login to ForgotPassword.

I feel like I overcomplicated things, but I don't know if (and how) it can be simplified.

The code:
LoginRoute.kt

```
@Composable
fun LoginRoute(
    viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    LoginScreen(
        uiState = uiState,
        onLoginClicked = {
            viewModel.acceptIntent(LoginIntent.LogIn)
        },
        onForgotPasswordClicked = {
            navController.navigate(NavigationDestination.ForgotPassword.route)
        }
    )
}
```

LoginNavigationFactory:

```
class LoginNavigationFactory @Inject constructor() : NavigationFactory {

    override fun create(builder: NavGraphBuilder, navController: NavHostController) {
        builder.composable(NavigationDestination.Login.route) {
            LoginRoute(navController = navController)
        }
        builder.composable(NavigationDestination.ForgotPassword.route) {
            ForgotPasswordRoute()
        }
    }
}
```

Do I really need to pass `navController` as an argument to the Routes? If I don't do it and simply do `rememberNavController` in the composable, it gives me NullPointers.

Answer (score 1):

I pass in a delegate and handle navigation at the top. I find this better practice

Comment: Welcome to code review! While it seems that [short answers are acceptable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1479/120114) are you able to expand this answer, perhaps explaining reasons for the suggestion?